# Выбор неповторяющихся случайных элементов из массива

Tags: java, массивы

Создаем массив чисел от 1 до 75, с помощью рандома чисел от 1 до 75 начинаем поиск элемента в массиве. Совпал - удалили. Ищем дальше. Совпал - удалили. Не нашли элемент - ищем снова пока не найдем.

Вот что вышло:

```
int[]array;
int num = (int)(Math.random()*75+1);//имитируем выпадение числа от 1 до 75
public int[] initArray(){//создаем, инициализируем и заполняем массив цифрами от 1 до 75 включительно
    this.array = new int[75];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        array[i] = i+1;
    }
    return array;
}
public static int findNumberInMass(int[] array, int num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (num == array[i]) {
            return i + 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;//вот тут он должен не найти нужный элемент и перезапустить поиск
}
```

Прошу помощи, а то голова кипит.
Как сделать так, чтоб он находил элемент выпавший в рандоме, искал его в массиве и удалял?
И чтоб он искал совпадения, а если не нашел то перезапускал рандом?

Comment: Зачем перезапускать поиск числа, которого в массиве нет?

Comment: Это все еще та же игра БИНГО. Выпало число от 1 до 75. Второй раз оно выпасть не может. Я сохранил 75 чисел в массив, теперь рандомно достаю их оттуда как бы ) Вот и прошу алгоритм ) Чую что что то не так )

Comment: У вас результат - знаковое целое, обычно если найдено возвращают нормальный индекс(без +1), а если не найдено `-1` Где клиентский код? Кто вызывает `findNumberInMass`?

Comment: Никакого клиентского кода. Я просто изучаю Java. Сам ставлю задачу, сам с ней воюю, если не получается - пишу сюда )  На правильность даже сейчас я не претендую, и поэтому жду критику )

Comment: Почему тогда вы не выбираете одно из чисел в массиве, а занимаетесь какими-то ненужными поисками?

Comment: А я и не знаю что так можно ) И спрашиваю что не то ) Спасибо за подсказку )

Comment: обозвали метод `nextNumber()`, выбрали в массиве случайный элемент, вернули его, тут же удалив из массива. Вроде всё.

Comment: как удалить его из массива ?

Comment: Придётся весь массив пересоздать заново. Лучше сменить структуру данных на какое-нить множество, или список.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то приведённый ниже код иллюстрирует её решение.

```
class Main {
    private final static int[] numbers = initArray();

    // Заполнение массива numbers числами от 1 по 75.
    private static int[] initArray() {
        final int[] array = new int[75];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
            array[i] = i + 1;
        return array;
    }

    // Поиск позиции числа n в массиве numbers. Возвращает -1, если число не найдено.
    private static int findNumber(final int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i)
            if (numbers[i] == n)
                return i;
        return -1;
    }

    // Получение следующего случайного числа.
    private static int nextRandom() {
        while (true) {                                // В бесконечном цикле...
            final int n = (int)(Math.random()*75+1);  // ... берём случайное число, ...
            final int pos = findNumber(n);            // ... и ищем его в массиве numbers.
            if (pos >= 0) {           // Если число найдено, ...
                numbers[pos] = -1;    // ... то "удаляем" его...
                return n;             // ... и завершаем цикл, ...
            }
        }                             // ... иначе возвращаемся к началу.
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        for (int ignored : numbers)
            System.out.println(nextRandom());
    }
}
```

Здесь применена небольшая хитрость. Во-первых, если мы не нашли число в массиве, то возвращаем заведомо невалидный индекс (`-1`). А во-вторых, поскольку удаление элемента массива выполнить без создания нового массива невозможно, то во избежание этой "дорогостоящей" операции мы просто помещаем в массив на место этого числа опять-таки заведомо невалидное значение (`-1`).

Comment: Хорошее, красивое решение, спасибо ! Буду разбираться.

Comment: `Удаляем его` - огонь) Я бы ушёл в дебри. Хотя, я и до сих пор считаю, что это решение не с того конца. Не нужно генерить число и искать его, нужно выбрать рандомное из оставшихся.

Comment: @vp_arth Это отличное решение! Думаю, будет не лишним, если Вы его реализуете и приведёте в качестве ответа на вопрос.

Comment: Если учесть что я работал только с массивами, а не с коллекциями, то это решение - ответ на вопрос. Четкий ответ на задачу. И тут как раз тот алгоритм который я себе нарисовал в голове. Он не лучший, но задача была такая. Сейчас пытаюсь через ArrayList и remove()

Comment: Я не очень хорошо знаю java, но попробую, прошу feedback.

Answer (score 5):

Более простое решение, есть класс(барабан), в котором при создании появляется N шаров, из которого мы можем достать случайный шар из оставшихся, с помощью `getNext`.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Game
{
  private LinkedList<Integer> drum;
  public Game(int N) {
    drum = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      drum.add(i+1);
    }
  }
  public int getNext() {
    if (drum.size() == 0) throw new java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException("No items more");
    final int i = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(drum.size()-1));
    return drum.remove(i);
  }
}

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("6 of 36 game");
    int N = 36;
    Game game = new Game(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      int selected = game.getNext();
      System.out.println("Item "+selected+ " was selected!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Хорошее, чёткое решение. Я бы сделал чуть иначе только в двух местах. Во-первых, использовал бы `int` вместо `Integer`, поскольку `int` "полегче" и вместо `Integer selected = drum.get(i); drum.remove(i); return selected;` написал бы `return drum.remove(i);`, поскольку `ArrayList.remove` возвращает удалённый элемент ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int) ).

Comment: Спасибо, исправил. `ArrayList` же нельзя от int создать?

Comment: Тьфу, блин! Пора спать.  Тяжёлый рабочий день даёт о себе знать. Начинаю путать языки... Извиняюсь. Действительно, в Java контейнер не может хранить примитивные типы, только объекты.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант решения с использованием ArrayList:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); // создание динамического массива
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int x = 0; x < 75; x++) {
        list.add(r.nextInt(76)); // заполнение массива случайными цифрами до 75
    }
    System.out.println("Initial list = " + list); // вывод заполненного массива в консоль

    while (list.size() > 0) { // выполняем цикл пока размер массива не уменьшиться до 0 
        for (int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++) {
            int num = r.nextInt(76); // выбираем случайное число для поиска в массиве
            if (list.get(x) == num) { // сопоставляем случайное число с элементами массива
                list.remove(x); // удаляем элемент в случае совпадения
                System.out.println(num + " was deleted");
                System.out.println(list); // выводим оставшийся массив
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Array is empty"); // по исчерпанию элементов массива
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Просто и без лишних заморочек:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Исходное значение макс. числа
    int length = 75;
    //Булевый массив, где помечается, какое из чисел использовалось.
    //По-умолчанию каждый элемент инициализируется как false
    boolean[] arr = new boolean[length];
    //Просто для наглядности общего кол-ва попыток найти число.
    int totalIterations = 0;
    //Всего должно будет вывестись 75 чисел,
    //поэтому ставим данное условие в цикле, но итерацией будем заниматься внутри
    for (int i = 0;i<length;){
        //Получаем рандомное значение
        final int n = (int)(Math.random()*length+1);
        //Если элемент с этим значением не был использован
        if (!arr[n-1]){
            //Выводим его в консоль
            System.out.println(n);
            //Помечаем как использованный
            arr[n-1] = true;
            //Производим итерацию
            i++;
        }
        //Дополнительно считаем общее кол-во итераций
        totalIterations++;
    }
    //Уведомляем об окончании
    System.out.println("Done! Total iterations: "+totalIterations);
}
```

Вариант с альтернативным подходом:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Исходное значение макс. числа
    int length = 75;
    //Кол-во перемешиваний
    int mixes = 1000;
    //Выводим итоговый результат
    for (int i: initArr(length,mixes)){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

static int[] initArr(int length, int mixes) {
    //Инициализируем массив
    int[] result = new int[length];
    //Заполняем значениями
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        result[i] = i+1;
    //Проходим по циклу заданное кол-во перемешиваний
    for (int i = 0; i < mixes; i++) {
        //Получаем рандомное первое значение
        final int first = (int)(Math.random()*length);
        //Получаем рандомное второе значение
        final int second = (int)(Math.random()*length);
        //Меняем местами значение по полученным выше индексам
        final int temp = result[first];
        result[first] = result[second];
        result[second] = temp;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Первый очень доходчивый и понятный ) Второй не совсем понятен, но щас по кускам его разнесу ) Спасибо !

Comment: @RattenGW. Суть второго алгоритма в том, что мы просто перемешиваем элементы массива заданное кол-во раз. Ведь в конечном итоге требуется "рассортировать" сортированный массив.

Comment: Я как бы могу придумать кучу алгоритмов, но я не знаю возможны ли они технически ) Еще раз всем спасибо !